# How to move old posts to another page to archive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a batman comic book page on my site http://www.batman-fansite.com

what i want to do is

Every month when the new issue comes out I want to be able to move a comic from RECENT COMICS into BACK ISSUES while still keeping all the comments and reviews for that page....

I'm lost on how to accomplish this if someone can point me in the right direction that would be awsome.

heres a link to the page http://www.batman-fansite.com/comics

Comment: What problems you have? Be more specific... What do you have? Provide more context

Comment: its not really a problem i just want someone to push me in the right direction....how to archive my new comics into a seperate page that lists all the previous comics

Comment: But do you have any idea how to do it? If so tell. Or your question will be closed to be much vague

Comment: if i knew how to do it i wouldn't be asking people on here how to do it?  Close my question if you want

Comment: I was just trying to help... People are more likely to answer if there is a good context and examples of what you have tried etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about scoping. The home page should have a query like this:

```
@current = Comic.order('published_at DESC').first
```

The archives are like this:

```
@comics = Comic.order('published_at DESC').all
```

When you have a larger number of entries you'll eventually need pagination, but for the first cut this is more than sufficient. As new entries are "published" they will automatically show up on the home page.

A more robust publishing model is where you can set the `published_at` time into the future:

```
@current = Comic.where('published_at<=NOW()').order('published_at DESC').first
```

You can even make a `scope` for this to clean it up further, but it has the same effect.

Comment: thanks man thats all i wanted a push in the right direction